# how to rename a file in a directory using current directory

Tags: bash, renaming

I want to rename a file (home/Desktop/ali/a/b.txt)

I wrote a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

mv a/b.txt a/c.txt
```

and put it in ali directory,I navigate to ali directory in terminal but when I execute the bash file it can't find a/b.txt

I know `mv home/Desktop/ali/a/b.txt home/Desktop/ali/a/c.txt` will work fine, but is there any way to use current directory to shorten the addressing?

Comment: you can use brace expansion... `mv home/Desktop/folder2/a/{b,c}.txt` .. not sure about what you mean by using current directory

Comment: I mean since I am in "ali" directory in the terminal, is there any way that my script find a/b.txt without giving full address in the script(home/Desktop/folder2/a/b.txt)?

Comment: If you are in *"ali"* directory, you will see that you can indeed use a shortened path if you do `ls -l a/b.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your response!
so I should try:
mv ls -l a/b.txt a/c.txt
?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, ali=folder2

Comment: `cd home/Desktop/ali/a; mv b.txt c.txt;`

Comment: I don't want to use the full address(home/Desktop/ali/a), since my working directory is ali, I want to use shorten version,like a/b.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `mv` a local file, just leave the dir blank:

```
mv a/test.py a/test1.py
```

Anyway you can use `pwd` for that, but keep in mind that you need to run the script in the same dir!

```
mv `pwd`/a/test.py `pwd`/a/test1.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's exactly what i wanted and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the location if you are in that directory.

For example you have file `A` in desktop so you navigate there and do:

`mv A B`

File `A` was renamed to `B` in that directory

But if you want to do so from another location then you do

`mv directory/A directory/newfilename`

Answer (score 0):

if you run script from Ali directory then your mv statement seems like

```
mv `pwd`/a/test.py `pwd`/a/test1.py
```

or

```
mv ./a/test.py ./a/test1.py
```